# Filling gaps / holes in a shapefile?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, editing, digitizing

I have a shapefile that looks like this:
[image]

I want to delete the holes, but I can't use any of the editing tools apparently...
[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Do you have a query applied to the layer? Check that layer's properties window in the General tab and see feature filter. Also another basic check is to make sure that layer is highlighted in the layer list.

Comment: @SaultDon Yes, I have it on purpose. So I could delete the small polygons.

Comment: Editing doesn't work with a feature filter =) You can maybe select those features instead (copy and paste your feature filter). Editing usually only edits the selected features.

Comment: Yeah I saved as a different shapefile before editing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn on the advanced digitizing toolbar - View > Toolbars

Then use the delete ring feature.

Comment: It's the same, there are more buttons but I cannot use them [picture](https://i.gyazo.com/daff5619bc0475afa8d0dd2cc2ef156b.png)

Comment: Have you made the layer editable? Click on the pencil icon to 'Toggle Editing' if you haven't.

Comment: And as SaultDon says, make sure the layer is highlighted in your layer list.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a feature filter applied. Editing doesn't work like that in QGIS so maybe consider using that feature filter and applying it as a selection.

This would require you to remove the feature filter, but editing should only apply to selected features.